# Describe an equivalence class

Tags: equivalence-relations

On the set **N** x **N**, define the following relation:

(*a*, *b*) ~ (*c*, *d*) if and only if *a* + *d* = *b* + *c*

(a). Show that this is an equivalence relation

I have shown that this is an equivalence relation by proving that the relation has a reflexive, symmetric, and transitive property.

(b). Describe the equivalence class of (1, 1)

I have a rather crude understanding of describing an equivalence class, but as far as I know, the equivalence class of (1, 1) is any value for (*c*, *d*) ∈ **N** x **N** in which 1 + *d* = 1 + *c*. So far, my guess is to describe (*c*, *d*) such that *c* = *d*, *c* - *d* = 0, 2 *d* = *c* + *d* = 2 *c*. Is there a 'Proper' way to describe it?

Comment: You can say it's the subset consisting of (c,d) such that c=d, or you can say it's all elements of the form (c,c) where c is in $N$. It's the same.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to how many descriptions I should give? I mean, there are lots of ways to describe it.  c = d, c - d = 0, 2d = c + d = 2c and thats just to name a few

Comment: Since they're all the same, you should just give one. But c=d is the simplest so I would go with that one. Or (c,c) where c is in N is perhaps simpler.